# Dataproc change worker size

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

My jobs (ML jobs) require more than 15GB RAM per worker. How to change the machine type for worker? Currently:

> n1-standard-4 (4 vCPU, 15.0 GB memory)

I would prefer to keep my cluster not recreate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change the machine type for an existing cluster - this is not something Dataproc supports. What is the reason you want to keep your cluster rather than create a new one?

Comment: I installed few libraries to support an application. Not big deal, just wanted to know I'm not missing anything obvious. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid it can be done following these steps:

1. Go to the VM instances section in the Compute Engine -> Instances
2. Stop the instance
3. Change the type machine
4. Start it

I have just done it and it worked. If a worker is shut down the cluster will continue working, but if you modify the master the cluster may not work after the change, in any case I recommend restart your cluster. Just be careful on doing this because [data stored may be removed](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/resources/faq#what_happens_to_my_data_when_a_cluster_is_shut_down) according to Dataproc documentation.